# Magento 2.0 "something went wrong"

Tags: magento2

[image: Something went wrong!]

I was doing that thing in that place when something happened.  What should I do?

(I am using Magento 2.0 and I am receiving these messages that "Something went wrong."  I do not see any stack traces in the log file.  Where is this message coming from, and how do diagnose?)

Comment: "I was doing that thing in that place when something happened." this is a joke, right? I mean, the error message is not meaningful, but that doesn't mean your question must have the same level of detail.

Answer (score 4):

The only place I can find that exact string is in `Magento_Ui/view/base/web/js/grid/provider.js` in the function `onError()`. It looks like anywhere in the admin a grid is being used, this component is initialized. I would start by looking at your xhr requests in the chrome inspector network tab and finding any responses that don't return a 200 code. If you can confirm that this ajax request is related to the action that gave you that alert message, you can go from there.

Answer (score 1):

You should see a report being generated under var/reports with more details on what went wrong. See https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/111218/2363 for more information.