# Magento 2.1.9 - Admin prodcuts grid not loading

Tags: magento2, admin, adminhtml, product-grid

Find below screenshot and I have also run the basic commands of magento as below.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cahce:clean
```

[image]

Comment: DId you check the log files and the Reports?

Comment: Please check this link, it may helpful to you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109224/magento-2-attention-something-went-wrong-clicking-contentblocks-page-doesnt?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: thanks chirag but this is also not working..

Comment: @SaravananDS yes, not any report orlog is generating and permissions are already there.