# Magento2 Error: "Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state" showing on the loop

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Whenever I open the Catalog Product it gives the following error on loop and continue loading the loader

> Attention Something went wrong.
>
> Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have
>   restored the filter to its original state.

I tried clear the cache`(php bin/magento cache:clean)`also upgraded magento`(php bin/magento setup:upgrade)`even given the files and folder permission but still facing the same problem.

[image: loading]

Comment: hi @rahul how did u fix this issue? can you please advise?

Comment: temporary fix is to clear (empty, not delete) the ui_bookmark table of your magento 2 database, this will reset the grid back to it's default and stop the infinite load.

Comment: I started having this issue after upgrade from 1.9.0.1 to 2.3.3 only when I tried to sort elements by some parameter. Though when I created another user it didn't have that issue. More like temporary fix but it worked for me.

Comment: For me, the underlying problem seems to have been a product that was missing its name attribute. I saw someone below had mentioned a null sku, which is what pointed me in the right direction. After adding a name record for that product to the catalog_product_entity_varchar table the message has not come back.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Old post but for future viewers - a temporary fix is to clear (empty, not delete)  the **ui_bookmark** table of your Magento 2 database, this will reset the grid back to its default and stop the infinite load.

```
 TRUNCATE ui_bookmark;
```

(you can find out your admin user ID in the **admin_users** table as well and only remove the `ui_bookmark` rows relevant to your account if this is a multi-admin site)

The actual problem can be harder to diagnose, but a good place to start (and in my case) was to increase the PHP timeout limit.

Comment: yes working after empty ui_bookmark! Thanks

Comment: Did not work for me using 2.2.5

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: not working after empty ui_bookmark! magento 2.3.2

Comment: Worked for me on magento 2.4.0

Comment: Thankyou so much worked for me on magento 2.3

Comment: yes it working for me @Rahul Singh you can accept this

Comment: Thanks, Same but I used the Delete query for a particular Admin user. It's working for me. 
DELETE FROM ui_bookmark WHERE namespace = 'sales_order_grid' AND identifier = 'current' AND user_id = '1'; /* your admin_user_id; */

Answer (score 17):

In My Case, It was due to that some null SKU related error I resolved using the following query.

***UPDATE catalog_product_entity SET sku='' WHERE sku IS NULL;***

run SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity` WHERE `sku` IS NULL to check all product not have sku, then update them

Comment: thanks, fixed my issue after a migration. so many things are wrong with the software

Answer (score 4):

It might be solved by cleaning the bookmarks database table using the command below.

```
TRUNCATE ui_bookmark;
```

In case it didn't solve the issue you can try to solve it by increasing the admin user session in this admin option below.

[image: Magento 2 Admin user session]

Comment: This was the correct answer for me, increasing the admin session size solved the issue on Magento 2.4.3-p1

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, this error is made by version upgrade. 
In my case, I upgraded Magento 2.2.7 to 2.3.1 and then I got this error in the product grid panel of backend. So I checked "catalog_product_entity" table in the database.
There were several products with NULL as sku value.
I made those skus empty and the error went away!!!
I hope this will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

Add rights for:

- Invoices
- Shipments
- Credit Memos

This will fix the error message.

Comment: This is working fine for me as well 
Thank you!

Comment: What does "Add rights for" mean?

Comment: Visit the user roles section in Magento admin, select the appropriate role and enable the checkboxes for Invoices, Shipments and Credit Memos under section:
Sales » Operations » Orders » Actions.

Comment: @Edd 
Thanks it's working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue for some Users which only had very restricted Access to the magento backend. Giving those users access to the product catalog fixes the immediate issue.

**Note that these users will be able to edit products** with that access, as there is no view-only access for the catalog -.-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This may help someone like me who using UI Component in area other than Admin.

I found this error in the front end/ seller portal. I'm using an extension that is using UI components to create grids in the seller portal.

I have created a new grid following examples from blogs that were created for the Admin area.

I observed the network request having `namespace` keyword throwing `302` status.

I found this error and it was due to the below code

```
<dataSource name="data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/ui/render"/>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
```

Later I searched in the extension itself and found the URL they have used instead of `mui/ui/render` for this kind of operation and that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

File open:

```
\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter.php
```

Function change:

```
public function apply(Collection $collection, Filter $filter)
{
    if (!$collection instanceof AbstractDb) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Database collection required.');
    }

    /** @var SearchResult $collection */
    $mainTable = $collection->getMainTable();
    $columns = $this->getFulltextIndexColumns($collection, $mainTable);
    if (!$columns) {
        return;
    }

    $columns = $this->addTableAliasToColumns($columns, $collection, $mainTable);
    $collection->getSelect()
        ->where(
            'MATCH(' . implode(',', $columns) . ') AGAINST(?)',
          //  $filter->getValue()
            $this->escapeAgainstValue($filter->getValue())
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This commit can solve your problem.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/14905

**Magento/Framework/View/Element/UiComponent/DataProvider/FulltextFilter.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Filter;
/**
 * Class Fulltext
 */
class FulltextFilter implements FilterApplierInterface
{
    /**
     * Returns list of columns from fulltext index (doesn't support more then one FTI per table)
     *
     * @param AbstractDb $collection
     * @param string $indexTable
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getFulltextIndexColumns(AbstractDb $collection, $indexTable)
    {
        $indexes = $collection->getConnection()->getIndexList($indexTable);
        foreach ($indexes as $index) {
            if (strtoupper($index['INDEX_TYPE']) == 'FULLTEXT') {
                return $index['COLUMNS_LIST'];
            }
        }
        return [];
    }
    /**
     * Add table alias to columns
     *
     * @param array $columns
     * @param AbstractDb $collection
     * @param string $indexTable
     * @return array
     */
    protected function addTableAliasToColumns(array $columns, AbstractDb $collection, $indexTable)
    {
        $alias = '';
        foreach ($collection->getSelect()->getPart('from') as $tableAlias => $data) {
            if ($indexTable == $data['tableName']) {
                $alias = $tableAlias;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ($alias) {
            $columns = array_map(
                function ($column) use ($alias) {
                    return '`' . $alias . '`.' . $column;
                },
                $columns
            );
        }
        return $columns;
    }
    /**
     * Escape against value
     * @param string $value
     * @return string
     */
    private function escapeAgainstValue(string $value): string
    {
        return preg_replace('/([+\-><\(\)~*\"@]+)/', ' ', $value);
    }
    /**
     * Apply fulltext filters
     *
     * @param Collection $collection
     * @param Filter $filter
     * @return void
     */
    public function apply(Collection $collection, Filter $filter)
    {
        if (!$collection instanceof AbstractDb) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Database collection required.');
        }
        /** @var SearchResult $collection */
        $mainTable = $collection->getMainTable();
        $columns = $this->getFulltextIndexColumns($collection, $mainTable);
        if (!$columns) {
            return;
        }
        $columns = $this->addTableAliasToColumns($columns, $collection, $mainTable);
        $collection->getSelect()
            ->where(
                'MATCH(' . implode(',', $columns) . ') AGAINST(?)',
                $this->escapeAgainstValue($filter->getValue())
            );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me. What solved the problem for me is related to the admin user roles configuration as described in this article:
https://medium.com/@teacha/magento-2-something-went-wrong-with-processing-the-default-view-and-we-have-restored-the-filter-9e2810733e71

When I provide all access to the orders section, the problem was solved. When access is partial, this error may appear. It's not ideal, especially if some users shouldn't have accesss to certains of the admin order page, but this is good solution for me until the bug is fixed by Magento.

Comment: By default admin having the all user role assigned, if you add any 2nd user and want to give the access of admin in that case you have to assign the role

Comment: @RahulSingh correct. I only had this issue with 2nd user role, not with my admin role.

Comment: then your solution is correct in this case

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting similar issue (Magento2.3.5-p2) when I had a user with limited access role to view the orders.

[image]

When I allowed the resources under ***Archive*** then after the issue was fixed.