# Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state

Tags: magento2, catalog, products

I got this error when I go to Catalog > Products and select a filter.

I'm on Magento 2.2.6.

Magento says this bug is supposed to be fixed on 2.2.6 but clearly it's not.And unfortunately I do not have enough credibility to comment on [this thread](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/232021/magento2-error-something-went-wrong-with-processing-the-default-view-and-we-ha) and ask what has to be changed to what.

Hoping this question will gain me some credibility hahaha.

Thanks!!!! :) :)

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue when I logged in as a non-admin role and have partial access to the resource.

If you are not an admin user, try logging in as admin and see if the issue persists. If the issue only shows up in the non-admin role, you can start enabling some related resource in **System -> User Role** (in your case, you can try enabling all product-related resources and see if it works for you)

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error was doubled by this one in `system.log`:

`report.WARNING: Session size of 271683 exceeded allowed session max size of 256000.`

I solved by increasing the value for the configuration key named`system/security/max_session_size_admin`.

example:
`bin/magento config:set -c system/security/max_session_size_admin 512000`