# imagecolorsforindex(): Argument #2 ($color) is out of range when running bin/magento catalog:images:resize

Tags: magento2, product-images, upgrade, bin-magento, image-resize

I recently upgraded from 2.4.4 to 2.4.5. While placing the images in pub/media folder and running bin/magento catalog:images:resize, I am getting the following error

```
imagecolorsforindex(): Argument #2 ($color) is out of range#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php(347): imagecolorsforindex(Object(GdImage), 48)
```

Any idea what went wrong and how to rectify it ?

[image]

edit :
It seems PHP GD Library gives error if Color went out of range.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorsforindex.php.

so index 48 is out of range, in previous version this returned false but now it throws error.
I had checked the view.xml, but still can't figure out the issue.

Comment: related PR im magento2 repo: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/36679

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did a workaround and it seems to work (not the actual solution).

I basically changed the default image adapter configuration of "Image Processing Settings" in ***Configuration>Advanced>Developer>Image Processing Settings*** from PHP GD2 to ImageMagick, and ran catalog:images:resize again after flushing image cache. This is a PHP GD2 library issue and no one had reported it yet.

Answer (score 8):

**vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php** around line 346:

```
-        if ($transparentIndex >= 0 && $transparentIndex <= imagecolorstotal($this->_imageHandler)) {
+        if ($transparentIndex >= 0 && $transparentIndex < imagecolorstotal($this->_imageHandler)) {
```

Comment: yes working for me Thanks @Konstantin G.

Answer (score 2):

this also works to solve the infinite scroll issue related to this error

Magento2 Error: "Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state"

this link shows temp fixes for error mentioned driectly above

[Magento2 Error: "Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state" showing on the loop](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/232021/magento2-error-something-went-wrong-with-processing-the-default-view-and-we-ha)

What I did

enabled dev mode, then changed the image processing to imagick, now back to prod mode.

This solved the load issue
This created ability to enter larger custom qty amounts in per page view of catalog/products page in magento 2.4.4 running php 8.1