# Magento 2 dynamic custom column in UI listing, sorting not working

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, uicomponent, list-view

I have create two columns "Sending" and "Remaining". The value of them is based on the "In stock" column. When i tried to sort the order of one of column then it doesn't work. It gives me an error.
eq In Stock = 10.
   Entered 3 in "Sending"
   Remaining column will change to 7.

The sorting doesn't work for both columns.

[image]

Comment: can you show your error log?

Comment: {"error":"UI component could not be rendered because of system exception","errorcode":"42"

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109224/magento-2-attention-something-went-wrong-clicking-contentblocks-page-doesnt this looks similar maybe start here?

Comment: Not able to get the solution.

Comment: so your file permissions are right and you aren't getting any ajax issues?

Comment: This is the ajax error.  {"error":"UI component could not be rendered because of system exception","errorcode":"42"

Comment: okay i didn't know where it came from

Comment: Any solution you have?

Comment: hmmm besides looking in var/report not really (if i had a good solution I would have answered not commented :) )

Comment: did you find solution this happens same to me.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you don't have a column in the database that matches the name of your two added fields. Magento takes the name from the xml file in which you specify the grid view and when you want to sort by this column it performs a database query in which it takes the column name from the xml file and tries to add it to the SQL query.

All you have to do is override method `\Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column::applySorting()`
You can do it simply by modifying your xml like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="your_column" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\YourColumn">
            <settings>
                <sortable>true</sortable>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

And write your own class `Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\YourColumn` that extends `\Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column`. I think something like that should work:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component;

use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class YourColumn extends Column
{
    /**
     * Apply sorting
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function applySorting()
    {
        $sorting = $this->getContext()->getRequestParam('sorting');
        $isSortable = $this->getData('config/sortable');
        if (
            $isSortable !== false
            && !empty($sorting['field'])
            && !empty($sorting['direction'])
            && $sorting['field'] === $this->getName()
        ) {
            $this->getContext()->getDataProvider()->addOrder(
                'enter here your db column name by which you want to sort',
                strtoupper($sorting['direction'])
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Bartosz for pointing me in the right direction. Because my ui_grid column was based on an entity_id but showed the related increment id, when sorting I would get this "UI component could not be rendered because of system exception". A quick fix based on your answer was to add <settings><sortable>false</sortable></settings> to my custom column so the customer no longer got this error. Now it works as it should.

Comment: It would been better if you had given an example for Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\YourColumn

Comment: @AveshNaik I added example, let me know what do you think.