# something went wrong with your request.please try again later

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

i am getting error like
something went wrong with your request.please try again later
in shipment page.

for reference please find the attached image.
[image]

Comment: check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109224/magento-2-attention-something-went-wrong-clicking-contentblocks-page-doesnt